# Make a list item of specific index bold with JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, collections, jstl

I have an ordered list of names, and I need to make the *third* item on the list bold. Only the third item should be bold. After that it should return to regular font. Here's what I have as of now:

```xml
<ol>
    <c:forEach items="${names}" var="entry" varStatus="status">
        <li>
            ${entry}
            <c:if test="${entry eq 'Jeff'}"> is a grader.</c:if>
            <c:if test="${entry eq 'jeff'}"> is a grader.</c:if>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
</ol>
```

Would I still be using `<b>` tags, or is there another way to bold certain text (using JSTL)?

Comment: <b> tags work, but if it's an option, you might want to explore how to use CSS to make something bold.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of the `varStatus="status"` you got there. It refers to a local [`LoopTagStatus`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html) instance which offers you among others the (self-explaining) `getIndex()` method.

```xml
<c:if test="${status.index == 2}"><b>This is the 3rd item.</b></c:if>
```

*(yes, also here, array indexes start at 0)*